# No "Select app" and "Select device" to choose in gmail "Security>App Passwords"

Tags: smtp, gmail

5 days ago I set a password for the application in my gmail. Later I had to delete it. Today I wanted to create a new one for a needed project and found that I don't have "Select app" and "Select device" to choose from, just one field to enter the name of the app only. Any ideas why I don't have this?

- only 2FA with phone number is on as should be.

*And this is how I currently have*:
[image]

*This is how it should be*:
[image]